# Is there a way to compare if a primitive type and an array are less than zero?

Tags: java

In java, you cannot use .compareTo() to compare primitive types (like an int) with something else.

Is there a way to compare if two integers are less than zero? I am trying to compare an integer to a spot in an array.

Thanks!

SOLVED: Sorry everyone, had a massive brain cramp for a second. I forgot that a.compareTo(b) returns -1, 0, or 1 based on if the first value is less than(returns -1), equal to(returns 0),or greater than (returns 1). My code said int.compareTo(array)<0 when really all it needed to say was int

Comment: There are so many different questions here; and not all of them make sense.

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
  if(firstinteger<0 && secondinteger<0){

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

`==` if compared against primitives will either perform [numerical or boolean equality](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21).  That said, for what you want, it should be as trivial as doing this:

```
if(firstValue < 0 && secondValue < 0) {
    // operate
}
```

**Remember:**  You only use `.compareTo` for references that implement `Comparable` (such as `Integer`, `Long`, etc).  You use `==` for all other numerical primitives.<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1: But watch out for floating-point values.  Those may not *always* equal each other.</sup>